# How much difference is there between the Pentax DA 55-300 and FA 80-320?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, zoom, telephoto, pentax

I currently have a Pentax FA 80-320, and it's very nice to have a long zoom available.  Lately, I've been considering "updating" to the DA 55-300.

I also have the DA 50-200, so the lower end of the range is covered, although I suppose I could replace both of those with the 55-300.  I don't think either of my current lenses is in high demand, so I probably wouldn't get much for them.

Are there any significant differences in optics?  What about the auto focusing?  Any other factors that I should consider in my decision?

Answer (score 2):

An important factor I don't see in your argument is *why* do you consider upgrading - what are you missing with your current lenses? I don't have hands-on experience, but based on reviews, the 80-320 seems to be a decent lens.

The 55-300 is just another consumer zoom. It's quite good in the wide end, but I find I have to stop mine down to about f/10 to get rid of softness in the long end (and I'm not normally a pixel peeper).

Comment: Other than lens acquisition syndrome, I could replace 2 lenses in my bag with one...but I'm basically wondering if technology has improved noticeably over the two lenses.